# Shopware 6: sw-inherit-wrapper for sw-snippet-field and sw-media-field component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, twig, shopware, shopware6

I am in the process of programming a custom administration module (plugin configuration) in Shopware 6 using Vue.js.

The problem I have encountered is the lack of sw inherit wrapper that shows up when the sales channel changes.

What I want is to reproduce exactly the same effect that would be here using the `config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/trunk/src/Core/System/SystemConfig/Schema/config.xsd">
    <card>
        <title>Configuration</title>

        <component name="sw-snippet-field">
            <name>content</name>
            <snippet>pluginConfiguration.content</snippet>
        </component>

       <component name="sw-media-field">
            <name>logoId</name>
        </component>
    </card>
</config>
```

So I started programming this code using Vue.js:

```
{% block custom_content %}
    <template #content>
        {% block custom_content_card %}
            <sw-card-view>
                {% block custom_card_channel_config %}
                    <sw-sales-channel-config v-model="config"
                                             ref="configComponent"
                                             domain="PluginExample.settings">

                        {% block custom_config_sales_channel %}
                            <template #select="{ onInput, selectedSalesChannelId }">

                                {% block custom_config_sales_channel_card %}
                                    <sw-card position-identifier="example-sales-channel-card"
                                             :title="$tc('global.entities.sales_channel', 2)">

                                        {% block custom_config_sales_channel_card_title %}
                                            <sw-single-select v-model="selectedSalesChannelId"
                                                              labelProperty="translated.name"
                                                              valueProperty="id"
                                                              :isLoading="isLoading"
                                                              :options="salesChannels"
                                                              @change="onInput">
                                            </sw-single-select>
                                        {% endblock %}
                                    </sw-card>
                                {% endblock %}

                            </template>
                        {% endblock %}

                        {% block custom_config_cards %}
                            <template #content="{ actualConfigData, allConfigs, selectedSalesChannelId }">
                                {% block custom_config_credentials_card %}
                                    <example-config-base
                                            :actualConfigData="actualConfigData"
                                            :allConfigs="allConfigs"
                                            :selectedSalesChannelId="selectedSalesChannelId">
                                    </example-config-base>
                                {% endblock %}
                            </template>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </sw-sales-channel-config>
                {% endblock %}
            </sw-card-view>
        {% endblock %}
    </template>
{% endblock %}
```

and this is my `example-config-base` component:

```
{% block example_config %}
    <sw-card position-identifier="example"
             :title="$tc('snippet.key')">

        {% block example_config_card_container %}
            <sw-container>

                {% block example_config_card_container_settings %}
                    <div v-if="actualConfigData">
                        {% block example_config_card_container_settings_snippet %}
                            <sw-inherit-wrapper
                                    v-model="actualConfigData['PluginExample.settings.snippet']"
                                    :inheritedValue="selectedSalesChannelId == null ? null : allConfigs['null']['PluginExample.settings.snippet']"
                                    :customInheritationCheckFunction="checkTextFieldInheritance"
                            >
                                <template #content="props">
                                    <sw-snippet-field
                                            name="PluginExample.settings.snippet"
                                            fieldType="textarea"
                                            snippet="pluginConfiguration.example"
                                            :mapInheritance="props"
                                            :disabled="props.isInherited"
                                    >
                                    </sw-snippet-field>
                                </template>
                            </sw-inherit-wrapper>
                        {% endblock %}

                        {% block example_config_card_container_settings_logo %}
                            <sw-inherit-wrapper
                                    v-model="actualConfigData['PluginExample.settings.logoId']"
                                    :inheritedValue="selectedSalesChannelId === null ? null : allConfigs['null']['PluginExample.settings.logoId']"
                                    :customInheritationCheckFunction="checkTextFieldInheritance">
                                <template #content="props">
                                    <sw-media-field name="PluginExample.settings.logoId"
                                                    :mapInheritance="props"
                                                    :media-id="props.currentValue"
                                                    @media-id-change="props.updateCurrentValue"
                                                    :disabled="props.isInherited">
                                    </sw-media-field>
                                </template>
                            </sw-inherit-wrapper>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                {% endblock %}
            </sw-container>
        {% endblock %}
    </sw-card>
{% endblock %}
```

According to the Shopware documentation, the `sw-snippet-field` does not store values in the system configuration, but changes the translations for the snippet key. This does not change the fact that it can use inherit wrapper. I don't know how to program it to get the identical effect if I did it in the config.xml file.

checkTextFieldInheritance:

```
checkTextFieldInheritance(value) {
            if (typeof value !== 'string') {
                return true;
            }

            return value.length <= 0;
        },
```

So for the moment, the only thing missing is the lack of purple color and this switch that unplugs the inherit value and sets the new one.

This is the effect I would like to achieve:

[image: plugin config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of snippet aren't bound to sales channels. They're bound to snippet sets and which set to be used it determined by the respective locale. The component `sw-snippet-field` uses the locale set in the current session for the language of its content. That's the language the currently logged-in admin user has set in their profile. If there is not content for a snippet with the current locale, it falls back to the systems default language. So even while you may be able to use that component in the configuration of your plugin, there'll be nothing to inherit, as the content is determined by the locale and also changing the sales channel in the configuration panel will not change that locale.

You could extend `sw-snippet-field` to accept a sales channel id by a property. By the sales channel id it could then resolve the locale by the default language of the sales channel.

```js
const { Component } = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;

Component.extend('my-custom-snippet-field', 'sw-snippet-field', {
    props: {
        salesChannelId: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
        },
    },

    computed: {
        salesChannelRepository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('sales_channel');
        },
    },

    watch: {
        salesChannelId() {
            this.isLoading = true;
            
            this.updatePlaceholderValueToSnippetTranslation().then(() => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
        },
    },

    methods: {
        async updatePlaceholderValueToSnippetTranslation() {
            const criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.addAssociation('language.locale');

            const salesChannel = await this.salesChannelRepository.get(
                this.salesChannelId, 
                Shopware.Context.api, 
                criteria
            );

            if (salesChannel?.language?.locale?.code) {
                const translation = this.getTranslationByLocale(salesChannel.language.locale.code);
                if (translation) {
                    this.textValue = translation.value;
                    return;
                }
            }

            await this.$super('updatePlaceholderValueToSnippetTranslation');
        },
    },
});
```

You'd then have to provide the means to select a sales channel and could pass the id of the selected sales channel as a property to your component extension. Usage would then look like this:

```html
<my-custom-snippet-field
    snippet="pluginConfiguration.example"
    field-type="textarea"
    :sales-channel-id="salesChannel.id"
/>
```

Comment: ok, it's perfect. Thank you. Is still trying to deal with the media field. I don't know how to program it. Catching the current value in inherit wrapper doesn't work, like for example custom field with media id. @dneustadt